# grub.cfg - wrong UUID - but only for the 4th UUID instance in each menu entry

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a number of system partitions.  My production partition is on sdd1. I have other partitions on sda7, 8 and 9.

I have been cloning partitions on sda7, 8 and 9 for backup/ testing - usually with Clonezilla. After cloning I generate a new UUID with tune2fs on the target partition and update its fstab.  I then do an update-grub (from sdd1).

In the newly generated grub.cfg (of sdd1) the grub menu entries for sdd1 have the correct UUID. sda7/8/9 have the correct UUIDs for the first 3 instances of the UUID in each menu entry, but the fourth instance of the UUID is incorrect.

I haven't tried to determine where the incorrect UUID is coming from - I think it is probably the previous value of the UUID for each partition. At the moment I am correcting the 4th instance of each UUID by hand - so that the correct partition boots when selected from the grub menu.

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue and how to correct it would be appreciated.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks. I'm not 100% sure but I think you're asking me to post the pastebin link to the Boot-Repair report. If not, please can you clarify? I have boot-repair installed on my primary system (on sdd1). Here is the link to the report - http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bWhV3YHhC2/.

Comment: Note sure if just not running update grub in each new install after correcting UUIDs? Part of reason I turn off os-prober and only add my own boot stanza to 40_custom as I have a lot of installs some obsolete that I do not want in grub menu. And I prefer to do a new install & copy /home if I want same settings, but usually testing something and do not want same settings. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13787835#post13787835 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: Definitely running update-grub after each install. That is how the first 3 UUID's in each grub menu entry are correct. It is just the fourth ("root=UUID=") that is incorrect.

Comment: I am not seeing that. And sda9 still shows Arch on sda7 so not updated, yet. Some of my typical entries, but review entire thread. Then I know which partition and do not need all the entries for every install in every installs.  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&page=54&p=13787835#post13787835 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen